# django db and sqlite use different parameter style?

Tags: django, sqlite

```
def getAppName(cursor, appId):
  cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM App WHERE id=?", (appId,))
  return cursor.fetchone()
```

I have a function getAppName, which will be called by raw sqlite cursor and django db cursor.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/#connections-and-cursors states django db cursor requires "%s" style placeholder, while raw sqlite cursor requires ? style placeholder.

How can my function be shared among django and regular applications?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly why it's better to use the ORM then to make direct raw SQL calls.  If you do, then the underlying ORM will automatically make the appropriate SQL changes depending on the engine.

So, `App.objects.get(id=appId).name` and your model would look like:

```py
class App(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

Then depending on your `DATABASE` setting, the appropriate engine would translate it into the right SQL for the database used.

Comment: The idea is good. But I have no authority to revise the other component written 10 years ago.

Comment: @Gqqnbig - Ah. Then you'll likely have to write an `if` statement where you test which database engine is used and write 2 SQL statements.  However you could still do what's stated above while the other component does raw SQL statements.  It's hard to guess without more details.